# Как найти наибольшую дату в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив объектов:

```
[
    {
     id: 1,
     time_update: "Tue Apr 13 2020 17:06:19 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     time_update: "Tue Apr 17 2020 17:06:19 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     time_update: "Tue Apr 11 2020 17:06:19 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
    },
    ...
]
```

Мне требуется вернуть массив объектов самых последних дат.

Написал функцию

```
private lastDateObjectInArray(data) {
        return data.reduce((a, b) => {
            if (a.time_update || b.time_update) {
                return new Date(a.time_update) > new Date(b.time_update) ? a : b;
            } else {
                return 'Не найдено';
            }
        });
    }
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как вернуть массив объектов (сохранив все соседние элементы), где будет несколько последних дат? Чтобы через аргумент в функции я передавал индекс, который бы указывал сколько последних объектов будет записано: `lastDateObjectInArray(data, index)`

Comment: Вам нужно правильно парсить вашу дату - она в каком-то странном формате. Конструктор `new Date` не понимает такой формат.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko new Date, как раз преобразует ее. Все правильно, код рабочий

Comment: @Fill, нет, не рабочий. возьмите каждую из дат что вы добавили, вставьте в new Date и посмотрите что вам вернется

Comment: StepanKasyanenko, @WVFFLIFE 
Извиняюсь, вы правы. Дело в том, что пишу на TypeScript, но он даже не ругнулся и вернул объект. Поправлю, но к вопросу это скорее не относится, дело в формате даты. [Поправил]

Comment: TS и не будет ругаться, откуда ему знать, какой формат строки вы передаете в конструктор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    time_update: "Tue Apr 13 2020 17:06:19 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    time_update: "Tue Apr 17 2020 17:05:19 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    time_update: "Tue Apr 11 2020 17:04:19 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
  },
];

function sortAndReduceArray(data, index) {
  return data.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(a['time_update']).getTime() > new Date(b['time_update']).getTime() ? -1 : 1;
    })
    .filter((_, elIdx) => {
      return elIdx < index
    })
}

console.log(sortAndReduceArray(arr, 2))
```

Comment: То что нужно, благодарю!